# Parsing XML elements without closing tags in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, fast-xml-parser

I am running into a problem with the [fast-xml-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser) npm package. I'm trying to parse some XML from an external source that has a series of elements with self closing tags but those elements have data in them that I need.
Consider the following snippet:

```
const options = {
    unpairedTags: ["link"]
};
const parser = new XMLParser(options);
const obj = parser.parse('<link something="idc" data="i care about this data"/>');
```

You can see that I have tried adding an [unpaired tag](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser/blob/HEAD/docs/v4/2.XMLparseOptions.md#unpairedtags) but obviously this doesn't work because the `idc` and `data` properties are not considered XML so `obj` still lands up being blank

Comment: Did you try adding the `htmlEntities: true` option to the parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default is to ignore attributes. Set the parse option `ignoreAttributes`

```
const options = {
  unpairedTags: ["link"],
  ignoreAttributes : false
};
```

https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser/blob/master/docs/v4/2.XMLparseOptions.md